# Setting up 3 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a 3-screen set up. Technically I only use 2. The third one is an HDTV for when I want to watch TV. Unfortunately, it's in another room and not visible from the work area. I already have it set up via audio preferences to create a virtual channel so that audio goes via BOTH 3.5mm and HDMI, and this appears to work.

Since I cannot see the HDTV (HDMI-1-1) from the work area, I want my second screen (on the right, HDMI-0) to mirror HDMI-1-1. That way, I can drag stuff to HDMI-0 that I want to watch on HDMI-1-1 and know what's happening there. The problem I am running into is that HDMI-1-1 is bigger and has a bigger resolution, so maximizing VLC or YouTube only makes it as big as HDMI-0, with HDMI-1-1 having visible, but not filled with video, space. How do I correct this? I want DVI Monitor to be my main monitor: on the left.

Lubuntu 18.04.2
https://pasteboard.co/I6faSlY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Restore to default workspace:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary --mode 1280x1024
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1600x900 --right-of DVI-0
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --off
```

Cinema mod:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary --mode 1280x1024
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1600x900 --right-of DVI-0 --scale-from 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as HDMI-0
```